# getting c++11 enum class functionality, with extra static members inside the class

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

I currently have many classical enums, and static arrays with corresponding strings (for (de)serializing from/to XML for instance)

```
namespace MyAppCommon
{
    enum Fruit { Banana, Apple, Orange};
    static const char * const fruitString[] = { "banana", "apple", "orange" };
}
```

In order to avoid increasing name clashes, I would like to use the c++11 `enum class` which avoids setting a dummy or redundant enum name such as `MyAppCommon::Fruit::e` or `MyAppCommon::Fruit::Fruit`

But how could I keep my static array inside the class? Such as:

```
struct Fruit:
{
    enum e { Banana, Apple, Orange};
    static const char * const string[] = { "banana", "apple", "orange" };
    e value;
}
```

The problem with this approach, is that I need to reimplement operator=, operator==, etc... to be able to use the enum members items directly, and it won't make the code nicer.

Comment: You may still do `fruitString[static_cast<int>(eFruit)]` (that you can put inside function).

Answer (score 3):

Either go all the way and implement your hack (will take some work like you said) or keep it simple. Enum classes are not allowed to have member fields or methods.

```
enum class Fruit {
    Banana, Apple, Orange
}
const char* FruitNames = {"Banana", "Apple", "Orange"};
const char* ToString(Fruit fruit) { ... }
Fruit FromString(const char* Name) { ... }
```

Name ToString and FromString the same for every Enum for template friendliness.

Comment: Agreed, I guess it boils down to the fact where the serialization should belong. If encapsulated in an object or in a separate part of the code dealing only with serialization.